NLog failed to write to some of the logging target when the application is running under certain user accounts
I encounter this issue in some of our production machines. When our service is running using account #1, NLog will fail to write to one of the targets.
If it matters, the workinglog below is written by logger created using LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(), whereas the nonworkinglog is written by logger created by LogManager.GetLogger(string name).
The problem does not happen when we run the service with account #2, or when running the service through command line.
NLog version is 4.7.11, and we're using .NET Core 6.
Here's the content of nlog.config.
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="NLog NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogFile="c:\logs\ABCFolder\nlog-internal.log"
      internalLogLevel="Info" >

    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets>
        <!-- write logs to file -->
        <target xsi:type="File" name="workinglog" fileName="d:\logs\ABCFolder\log-own-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message} |${all-event-properties} ${exception:format=tostring}" /> <!-- this is working -->
        <target xsi:type="Console" name="logconsole"
                layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message} |${all-event-properties} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
        <target xsi:type="File" name="nonworkinglog" fileName="d:\logs\ABCFolder\Subfolder\sublog-${longdate}.json"
            maxArchiveDays="14" layout="${message}" /> <!-- this is NOT working -->
    </targets>

    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>
        <logger name="SecondLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="nonworkinglog" final="true" />
        <logger name="Hangfire*" maxlevel="Off" final="true"/>
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" final="true" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="workinglog" />
    </rules>
</nlog>

I expected both targets to be written correctly with any accounts as long as the account has write permission to the log folder. However, it's only writing to the workinglog target.
In NLog's internal log, I see that both targets and loggers are successfully read, but there are some lines missing related to the nonworkinglog. Aside from that, there is no error logged there.
The following lines are missing when using the problematic account:
Debug Targets for SecondLogger by level:
Debug Trace => nonworkinglog
Debug Debug => nonworkinglog
Debug Info => nonworkinglog
Debug Warn => nonworkinglog
Debug Error => nonworkinglog
Debug Fatal => nonworkinglog

I have given full control permission for the log folder and its subfolders to both accounts.
Are there any other permission that I need to give?

does d:\logs\ABCFolder\Subfolder\sublog-${longdate}.json exist ? , if not, what does the name look like internally to the program? , is it locked by another user ... , have you tried changing directory path ... .

@ticktalk It should be created by the logger, isn't it?
And since it's supposed to be a new file, I don't think it's locked by other user.
I did try to change the directory to the parent "\ABCFolder", but it's still not writing there.

Try swapping files,directories about, only writing one or the other . .  Try various.... l permutations , double check logs, disk space, ...

If Nlog doesn't dump the configuration for SecondLogger, then maybe no Logger is created with name SecondLogger when running with "non-working"-account.

@RolfKristensen It's not created automatically as long as we set it in nlog.config? Is this due to some missing permission? If so, any idea what kind of permission is required?

@mottledmotmot It is the application (and not NLog) that decides when it creates NLog Logger with the name SecondLogger

@RolfKristensen When does the application creates the logger? When GetLogger() is called? If so, what could make this call fail, as in my case?

@mottledmotmot Yes the NLog Logger is created when calling LogManager.GetLogger("SecondLogger"). Maybe the call is not failing, but just never reached/executed ?
